# Analytical Badge still showing "FAQ"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, analytical-badge

I just noticed that the FAQ link at the top of the page is replaced with "help". However, the description of the Analytical Badge is still "Visited every section of the FAQ".
Shouldn't this also be changed to "Visited every section of the helpcenter" or something like that?

Also how will this badge be awarded now? Do you have to click on every link in the helpcenter to get this badge or do you just have to take the tour now?

Update:
The description of the tag is now `Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)` so the issue is solved!

Comment: SE should probably just do a global search and replace on the word "FAQ".

Comment: @RobertHarvey you should probably change that to "F-A-Q" or something.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The Analytical badge will no longer be awarded. It doesn't make sense to change it to "visited every page of the help center" because there's so much more content than in the old FAQ. Furthermore, this new help center is meant to be more reference material than single-sitting reading.

This is just like the "beta" and "precognitive" badges on Stack Overflow; you simply can't earn them anymore.

Comment: So, I can keep my Analytical badges?

Comment: That, or resell it for a handsome profit.

Comment: Nice, now their value has just increased x10000! :-D

Comment: A counterpoint: Since the Help Center is so much more detailed, perhaps it would still work as a badge. People would see specific articles and perhaps be encouraged to at least gloss them over.

Comment: Perhaps the badge description should be updated to reflect that. Currently, it talks about the FAQ as if it still exists, even linking the word FAQ to the new help center.

Comment: It's on my list, just haven't gotten to it yet.

Comment: I am glad I looked this up instead of going through the FAQ a 4th time.  By the way, I was sidelined by the Area 51 badge for a second too.  **Suggestion:**  Since the link to the badges page is "View a full list of badges you can earn", it should list the badges one can earn.  ;)  ...or at least group the obsolete badges together at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @Laura do you have any idea when you get time to change the badge? It has already been 2 weeks since I've asked this question.

Comment: @Daanvn The description will be updated in the next build (later today).

Comment: If it can't be awarded anymore, then stop showing it on the list of badges.

Answer (score 11):

We've now retired the [Analytical] badge. Meaning: nobody will lose it, but we won't award it.

[image: retired badge]

As part of that, I've removed the link.

Comment: Would it make sense to remove it from the unearned view, even for people that don't have it, because they can't possibly get it?

Comment: @Troyen we debated it, but we think it's better if all badges are either earned or unearned.