# Why does the badges list have inactive badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

I've read that badges like "Analytical" or "Beta" can [no longer be earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183243/224773). Shouldn't these badges be removed from the list?

Comment: No. Some people still have those badges. They still exist even if they can't be earned.

Comment: Historical significance :P

Comment: @hammar What about Precognitive then? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As correctly mentioned by [@hammar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183735/why-does-badges-list-still-have-unactive-badges#comment560935_183735), these badges are still listed because users still have them. Badges are [never revoked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)* or reversed. If these were removed then the next meta post would be:

> How can users have badges that don't exist?

<sub>Taken from the [How to badges work meta FAQ post:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)</sub>

> Tag badges, on the other hand, disappear immediately if you ever cease to meet their criteria, which could happen through deletion or downvotes.

> * *Not including tag badges or badges obtained by "heinous cheating"*

Answer (score 0):

The [Badge List](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) is a list of badges that users *can get or could have gotten previously*. Since those two badges are can still be kept by users, they should still be shown on the list.