# Should unearnable Badges been shown under unearned?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, badges, help, help-center

Should unearnable Badges been shown under unearned?

- [Beta] Actively participated in the private beta (if the site is not anymore beta)
- [Precognitive] Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase (it the site is online)
- [Guru] Accepted answer and score of 40 or more (on some new sites it is impossible: there must be at least 40 tags with 200 questions)
- [Analytical] Visited every section of the FAQ (Is also not earnable anymore since there is no FAQ anymore.) Reported by Daanvn.

Comment: Where is that list of "unearned" badges?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=unearned

Comment: Why? Also, Guru is not impossible. It might not be possible early on, but it will eventually become possible as the site grows.

Comment: @rekire Thank you, I just saw it now. It doesn't appear in Meta, only in the main site.

Comment: @Yannis I wrote *"on some new sites it is impossible..."* so I know that :-) but however that one can be unearned for the moment.

Comment: @rekire - I think *Analytical* badge can be earned by visiting [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) instead of FAQ.

Comment: If we start hiding badges that can't be earned at the moment, we'll have to hide _a lot_ of them on young sites. An example would be   Famous Question, 10,000 views is not really something that can happen in a young beta site.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183735/why-does-the-badges-list-have-inactive-badges/183736#183736

Comment: @Yannis IMHO there is a great difference if something unreachable or impossible.

Comment: @hims056 take a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183243/218170) on a question I asked about the Analytical badge, it cant be earned anymore.

Comment: @Daanvn - Didn't know about that question. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The current behavior is fine.

The unearned page is meant to show one the badges they don't have. The badges that you mention fall in this category.

I would find it much more awkward if there were badges that are neither earned or unearned!

Comment: I disagree with you. I see there no problem to show them under all badges, but the list unearned is for me some kind of list of Achivments to get and I cannot get them. So far this makes no sense for me.

Comment: @rekire That's the point, to realize that you can't get them all, and stop obsessing about them.