# "Informed" badge on meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, badges

There is an "Informed" badge for reading the meta about page but it was awarded zero times and to make sure I tried reading the about page but did not receive it.
If the badge is to be awarded here, then this should be 'fixed'. If not, it should be removed from the list of badges.

Comment: @Mat This is not a duplicate because the other person was asking why the badge was not seen specifically in meta stack overflow while I'm talking about this meta website. If the badge is not to be awarded on this website then it shouldn't be in the list of badges.

Comment: This website is what used to be Meta Stack Overflow, at the time that other question was asked.

Comment: Oh then I suggest removing the badge from the list of badges (or awarding it for metas).

Comment: Then edit your question with that suggestion, and retag with [feature-request].

Comment: @Mat alright done!

Comment: Almost dublicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185009/171881

Comment: Actually, it has been awarded one time (and recently, too). I don't know how it was done.