# Is the "Informed" badge broken?

Tags: bug, badges

I notice that the [Informed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/informed) doesn't get awarded after you read the entire tour page, as it does on other stack exchange sites. It also doesn't claim it is retired (as for example the "Analytical" badge does). Finally, only 14 have ever been awarded, which seems a bit low given that 173K have been given out on Stack Overflow. Is this a bug or a deliberate design choice that is undocumented?

Comment: Related: [“Informed” badge on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231035/informed-badge-on-meta) and [Why was one Informed badge awarded here on Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240728/why-was-one-informed-badge-awarded-here-on-meta)

Comment: Works for me ....

Comment: @rene tell the secret please :D How?

Comment: @nicael don't tell me the master hacker doesn't know....

Comment: @rene u mean needz a computer? Only in 16hrs. Ok

Comment: Not really a bug, more like a "too minor oversight". Low chance it will be changed, those who want the badge can use the hack.