# Analytical badge awarded recently

Tags: support, badges, analytical-badge

I was browsing badges right now, and saw that the `Analytical` badge has been retired. I tried searching how to get one, but found out that it cannot be obtained now - thanks to **[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq)** question.

Well, I was shocked to see that on clicking on that badge, there were several users who *had* obtained the badge recently - as recently as `3 hours ago`. Is that a bug, or is there some hidden way to obtain the badge still?

[image]

Comment: Shocked? Really?

Comment: In Damith case it seems to be a bug on all his badges: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2558060/damith?tab=activity&sort=badges&page=1 all appear to be earned one day ago.

Comment: Account merge perhaps @fedorqui? The same seems to be the case for Ethan Cabiac...

Comment: Could be... or such an intense day :)

Comment: The last four badges show different earning days, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2562358) got around 20 badges in the same instant, see his [badges activity filter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2562358/ethan-cabiac?tab=activity&sort=badges&page=1).

This happened due to account merge, in such case the badges are awarded in the time of merging. This has been confirmed [by a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188029/analytical-badge-awarded-recently/188030?noredirect=1#comment802463_188030). (who can see merge actions)

Bottom line, the old account having the badge has been merged into his main, newer, account and all badges have been re-calculated.

Comment: Damn it, for some time I thought I could get myself one of the retired shinies!

Comment: Nope, not unless you find old account of yours with the badge and merge it with your existing account. :)

Comment: The pattern that you noticed about all the badges being awarded same time is repeated for all other users. __[1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2539445/s-varun?tab=activity&sort=badges&page=1), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2556117/fraser?tab=activity), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2529645/ben-duffin?tab=activity)__

Comment: Yep, on second thought account merge is the only sensible option, edited to reflect this.

Comment: I was checking today the badges site and I've seen that the Analytical badge was awarded. It cannot happen by account merging, because there is one account which got this badge recently and has only one reputation.

Comment: @IrgendwPointer guess you mean [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2816301/devin-calado)? Reputation is not relevant, the old account (that did get the badge) might have 0 reputation. The "member for" says 6 months.

Comment: @ShadowWizard tha badges are still being awarded..

Comment: @Mr.Alien no. Only as result of merging.

Comment: @ShadowWizard got it...

Comment: @Shadow I can confirm that these are from account merges.

Comment: Thanks @animuson I've edited the post.

Comment: You can also get merged by a bot. Which is mostly just annoying. But there is hope!