# Precognitive badge earned *long* after site has launched

Tags: support, badges

Over on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) I noticed that a number of users received the [Precognitive badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/67/precognitive) "shortly" after the site launched - exactly 56 users on Dec 9, 2010, roughly 5 months after the site launch. However, there has been a total of 71 awarded in total with the latest recipient being awarded the badge almost 2 1/2 years after the first.

How is this possible?

Comment: I'm guessing these people may have followed the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) proposal, but only became an official user of the site much later. However, I'm unable to confirm this.

Comment: I guess those are due to account merging, same way that [Analytical badge still gets awarded sometimes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188029/analytical-badge-awarded-recently).

Comment: I'm not sure there is actually anything in the badge check that limits users from receiving the badge far into the future. As long as they followed the proposal, whenever they create their account they can get the badge. For example, [the most recent user to receive it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12646/user12079) got it a year after they registered there, when they apparently associated their account to the rest of the network (according to the association bonus timestamp), thus connecting them to Area 51 and their follow of the proposal.

Comment: @animuson: My suspicion is exactly that. But after finding the same user on Area 51 (by [viewing their Network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/44529/devoured-elysium?tab=accounts)), and searching through the [commitment phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148?phase=commitment) I was unable to find the user...

Comment: @Werner They may not have committed. That badge has nothing to do with the commitment phase. You follow in the definition phase. I'm not sure if there's even a way to view a list of followers.

Comment: @animuson: True (Precognitive = follow *before* commitment phase), and I see what you mean... there's no easy way to identify followers. Maybe on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @Werner Area 51 isn't on SEDE. ;)