# Why did this former staff member get all these badges at once?

Tags: support, badges, merge-accounts

I was browsing the list with recently awarded badges for [popular questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26?page=2), when I noticed former staff member [Lisa Park](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/771289/lisa-park) getting 9 instances of this badge at the same time.

The description of this badge reads:

> Question with 1,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

[image]

[image]

If you look at all the other times this badge was awarded it is completely at random times. I have scrolled through a load of pages of the awarded badges, but haven't seen anyone receiving two badges at the same time at any other point.

The view counts for these questions are all multiple's of 1000, so that seems legit, but it would be extremely coincidental that all these questions hit a multiple at exactly the same time.

Was there some outage in the badge script, so that there was some backlog to be processed at this time, or is there some automated traffic that caused these badges to be awarded?

Regarding the comments by Shadow:
It sounds like a logical explanation, but I doubt that is what happened in this case. There is a [snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20220614220128/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/771289/lisa-park) of the profile of Lisa Park of 14 June in the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/), questions that received the badge were already on her profile at that time.

Comment: My guess is account merge at work, doing the usual weird problems.

Comment: Finally [found what made me think of merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188029/analytical-badge-awarded-recently). Not closing as duplicate myself, but it's at least very much related and possibly the same issue.

Comment: I guess it really is [a merging.... issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DanT3.png).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at the [first Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20210826171021/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) of [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release), you'll notice the link to Lisa's profile: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/452001/lisa-park. She now has another user ID: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/771289/lisa-park so this is definitely the result of a user merge.

Comment: Good catch, should have though to check the post in the wayback machine.

Comment: *You earned a new badge: Investigator*