# How can i visit every section of FAQ?

Tags: discussion

The way to earn the 'Analytical' badge is: Visited every section of the FAQ (retired). What does (retired) mean? Does it mean that it is no longer available?

Comment: In short: yes it means it's no longer possible to earn this badge same way we can't earn the [Beta badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta) on Stack Overflow or any other graduated site.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it does.

The [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188733) says:

> As of June 2013, this badge [is no longer awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183243/152859) due to the FAQ being
>   changed to the Help Center all across the network. Those who earned it
>   previously get to keep it.