# What is the meaning of a retired badge?

Tags: support, badges

On Stack Overflow the "**Analytical**" badge has its description as *Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)*.

What is the meaning of the term **retired**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Retired* here means that the badge is no longer awarded.  It has been replaced by the **Informed** badge, which is given when the entire Tour page has been read.

This occurred when the [FAQ was replaced with the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183128/300411) and it no longer made sense to distribute the badge.