# Is the analytical Badge unretired? Then how is it received at present?

Tags: discussion, badges

There is

> Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)

at these questions [Analytical Badge still showing "FAQ"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq) and [What is the meaning of a retired badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280280/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-retired-badge)

But there is

> Visited every section of the FAQ

without

> (retired)

at https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Is the analytical Badge unretired? Then how is it received at present?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The section named itself "Retired Badges", so all the badges in the section are retired.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Retired Badges]

Comment: ... and when you click on the "Analytical" button, it brings you to a page that also states "This badge is retired and is no longer awarded."

Comment: Its probably worth adding that the informed badge replaced it, for all intents and purposes

Comment: Also note: There are some retired badges that appear to have been awarded after the badge was retired, but these are all the result of merging an account that had the badge.