# Should it be possible to flag questions to be closed as obsolete?

Tags: discussion, flags, meta, obsolete-information

[How come I can award badges to myself without meeting the requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109417/how-come-i-can-award-badges-to-myself-without-meeting-the-requirements) was a clever meta question, but it is obsolete for several reasons (talks about a retired badge, feature I can't identify in current SE implementation, and "hack" that no longer applies to anything).

Should a question like this be closed?

If so should should a low-level user just flag it for moderator attention, or should the reasons to flag to close include something along the lines of "obsolete"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, questions like that should be closed with the following off-topic sub-reason:

> The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

If you don't have the privilege to close-vote you can flag it with the same topic. That will send the question into the Close vote queue. If 5 members agree with your flag/close vote the question will be closed.

I did cast a close-vote on the question you choose as an example.

Comment: Ah ha -- thank you!  I didn't realize that was a sub-sub-reason.  Which leads to this request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236507/list-off-topic-sub-topics-in-flag-posts-documentation

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a close option on sites like [Super User](https://superuser.com/).