# List off-topic sub-topics in flag posts documentation

Tags: support, flags, help-center, documentation

Could you add an enumeration of the "off-topic" flag options to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts?

I didn't realize that (unintuitively) buried at that third level was an option I should be using (which led to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236491/should-it-be-possible-to-flag-questions-to-be-closed-as-obsolete)).

Perhaps a decision-tree version/diagram of the flagging guide would help newer users who come across a question and say, "*I think there's something wrong with this, but should I just dump it in the mod queue with my note or is there already a flag for this?*"  Or should we not worry about the moderator load and err on the latter action when we don't know?